# A good heuristic for computationally less intensive yet good K-medoids?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Can we use the data point in the cluster closest to the mean as the medoid?  Does this always give a medoid that is equivalent to running pair-wise distance measures as required by definition of how the k-medoid algorithm works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at both

- CLARA
- CLARANS

Who both aim at accelerating PAM (k-medoids) via random sampling?